# TModLoader reports a file to be missing when its not

Tags: c#

I'm Making a terraria Mod that adds all sorts of Junk, but one single issue keeps hitting me: It Thinks one of the Items needed does not exist.

The error I seem to be getting is:

```
 The item Copper Shortsword Stack of twenty does not exist in the mod GrandFinale.
If you are trying to use a vanilla item, try removing the first argument.
   at Terraria.ModLoader.ModRecipe.AddIngredient(Mod mod, String itemName, Int32 stack)
   at GrandFinale.Items.OmegaHeadbutt.AddRecipes() in c:\Users\sjpar\Documents\My Games\Terraria\ModLoader\Mod Sources\GrandFinale\Items\OmegaHeadbutt.cs:line 32
   at Terraria.ModLoader.RecipeHooks.AddRecipes()
```

Even Though The item exists here (full code)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace GrandFinale.Items
{
    public class TwentyStack : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.name = "Copper Shortsword Stack of twenty";
            item.width = 40;
            item.damage = 1;
            item.melee = true;
            item.height = 40;
            item.toolTip = "This is a modded sword.";
            item.useTime = 20;
            item.useAnimation = 20;
            item.useStyle = 1;
            item.knockBack = 6;
            item.value = 10000;
            item.rare = 2;
            item.autoReuse = true;
            item.UseSound = SoundID.Item7;


        }
        public override void AddRecipes()
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient("Copper Shortsword", 20);
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.WorkBenches);
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

And Is Being Called By this Other Item:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace GrandFinale.Items
{
    public class OmegaHeadbutt : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.name = "Omega Slash";
            item.damage = 10000;
            item.melee = true;
            item.width = 40;
            item.height = 40;
            item.toolTip = "The Sword Of The Ancients. Using it deals 499 Damage to the user, to deal 10,000 Base Damage";
            item.useTime = 20;
            item.useAnimation = 20;
            item.useStyle = 1;
            item.knockBack = 6;
            item.value = 10000;
            item.rare = 12;
            item.UseSound = SoundID.Item7;
            item.autoReuse = true;
        }


        public override void AddRecipes()
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(null, "Copper Shortsword Stack of twenty", 2);
            recipe.AddIngredient("Flask of Poison", 2);
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.WorkBenches);
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

(The Null on the line beginning tells of recipe.AddIngredient tells TModLoader that the item needed for crafting belongs to a Mod (not vanilla))

Any Help?

Comment: FYI, These Are not finished, but they are in a state where they work fine (i just need to tweak rarity and tooltips, and The Game can load the mod without them, if needs be.)

Answer (score -2):

You are getting an error because you are messing up the C# syntax in the mod recipes section (You can't have "" in () thats just how it works m8)
You messed up at these places:
 recipe.AddIngredient("Copper Shortsword", 20);
  recipe.AddIngredient(null, "Copper Shortsword Stack of twenty", 2);
   recipe.AddIngredient("Flask of Poison", 2);

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use strings inside parenthesis? This is most definitely not the problem since this is how you reference items when modding Terraria.